# GPO backup fails

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

When trying to backup a GPO using the GP management console (choosing the GP to backup, right click, hitting backup, and choosing a target directory "c:\ADB"), the backup fails.

In the Application eventvwr I can see the error is:

```
Backup of GPO failed. Error [The filename or extension is too long.]
```

But the detials are :

```
 Details -
     Source GPO:
          DisplayName: Default Domain Policy
          ID: 
          Domain: accad.int

      Backup:
         Directory: \\share\
         Instance : 
         Comment  :
```

Which doesn't help me...

How can I get to the file that fails?

How can I turn on logging that can show me how to do it?

Is there any command line method to run this backup?

---

After running:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator> import-module grouppolicy
PS C:\Users\administrator> Backup-Gpo "Default Domain Policy" -Path c:\ADBackup -Comment "Backup-08-22-14"
Backup-GPO : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 c
haracters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At line:1 char:11
+ Backup-Gpo <<<<  "Default Domain Policy" -Path c:\ADBackup -Comment "Backup-08-22-14"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Backup-GPO], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.PathTooLongException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.BackupGpoCommand
```

I still don't know where to start looking for the specific path / directory that is problematic...

THANKS!!

---

Since I couldn't find any small app that searches files with path longer than... - I wrote one.
You can find it at :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pathlength/

It's a very small application that allows you to search the conditions that the AD (or generally apps) require. 
The only thing to remember - run it on the DC that hosts the policies files (since in my case  - the share name was shorter, but the c:...\SYSVOL was longer.

hope it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to troubleshoot a little further. Are you able to backup other GPOs? Did you try using an alternative admin account? Can you create a test one and back that up? If you can, then I would check permission on the previous GPO where you are receiving the error.

There is a powershell command you can use:

> Backup-Gpo -Name MYGPO -Path C:\GpoBackup -Comment "Backup-08-21-14"

Comment: Hey, I left the office already, I'll try it first thing in the morning and let you know.
I have not tried neither - a different user nor powershell script.. didn't even know it would affect. I'll let you know tomorrow :) thanks!!

Comment: I ran the backup that way - and although got a bit more information (path is longer than X chars) - it still doesn't direct me to the specific path that I need to shorten..

I also think that the paths in the backup are relative to the root, so it would not be the NTFS path that is too long.. so I really wanna find the file from a backup log, and not from an OS search.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen my update? still stuck with it...

Comment: One other way you can backup is simply copying Policies folder. You can write a simple script to automate this process or do it manually. So basically in Windows Explorer, open: `\\local.domain\SYSVOL\local.domain\Policies` folder and copy it somewhere. In order to troubleshoot your particular issue, did you try installing RSAT tools on a Windows 7/8 machine and make a gpo backup using the gui?